# Android hms notification second click don't work as needed

Tags: android, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

I have notifications from huawei push kit with click_action  : {type : 3 }.
When app is in background. I recieve 2 or more notification. After click on first notification (don't matter first position or last in notifications on the screen) all works fine. App open launcher activity and I recieved data from the intent in onCreate. But then app is not in background allready and I click next notification and nothing happen. (Normaly it would trigger onNewIntent in the launcher activity and I can recieve data from intent). Why it may happen?

What I'am doing. Frist I close app. Than send two push notification.
Than click on one notification (app opens and go to needed fragment, all fine). Than click on another notification, while app is open after fist notification click. And nothing happen(onNewIntent don't triggered). From docs: when app is closed, notifications  processed by NC, and whith clic_type: 3 (open app) with opened app onNewIntent must be calld, if I'm not mistaken.

HuaweiLogs - [HuaweiLogs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D92SwTRFdb3r5vnRlAxasSxXg1cj-hHK/view?usp=sharing)

[Video Example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jXTN0p-S1PdVvUl3aJDvbnFmRD-RrbWU/view?usp=sharing) - (Procedure: 1)close app 2) Send two identical push, that lead on the same page 3) Click to first push (1:05 time), all works fine 5) go to another page 5) click second push and nothing happen)
[image: HmsTest]

Notifications are sends from backend like this:
[image: Notification]

[image: UpdateActivityManifest]

click logs - [click logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cwHsQX8MPgPR-6QI3DPZssapYOoIAbbs/view?usp=sharing)

[log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LwatXc29GiHhJdKZR6cNSb6brPprWUgy/view?usp=sharing) logs from project menu

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the log information printed in the `onNewIntent` method?

After testing, I find that the `oncreat` method is triggered when I click it for the first time, and the `onNewIntent` method is triggered when I click it for the second time. The following figure shows the test result:

[image]

Comment: Add screenshot in start topic

Comment: @dlpdlp Is `Updateactivity` the startup page?  could you mind post your manifest file for us to check?

Comment: yes, UpdateActivity is startup page.
It has :
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> in manifest

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you provide the parameters for sending messages and more detail logcat logs of the client for us to check?

Comment: add update with screenshot how I send messages. But I don't know which logs I can add, because on second notification click happen nothing. (with first click app start normaly with onCreate, second click (when app was in background but became foregrund after first click) nothing happen, onNew intent don't triggered)

Comment: you could capture logs by the following method: 1.Connect the ADB tool to your device and run the following commands:`adb shell setprop log.tag.hwpush VERBOSE` `adb logcat -v threadtime 1> D:\hwpush.log` 2.Try to reproduce the problem for which you want to capture logs. 3.Press Ctrl+C to capture logs.

Comment: also, can you please provide the parameter settings of `UpdateActivity` in your manifest file?

Comment: add logs and screenshot UpdateActivity settings from manifest

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, could you kindly help us with some more info to locate this issue? 1.The device model, EMUI and Android OS version. 2.Print log recorded the first click and second click app lifecycle changes of the `UpdateActivity` during drop-down notification panel to click messages.

Comment: add url for file with logs when I click on notifications. All info about device and os you can see in video (Video example url)

Comment: Would you please confirm that the [tab page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBve8.png) here is written in fragment? Check whether is redirected to the fragment after the notification is clicked for the second time. If it is convenient, print the life cycle in the fragment. If still nothing happens, and the life cycle is not printed, provide the log of the system.

Comment: Dial `*#*#2846579#*#*`Enter the project menu. - 1. Background settings - 3. AP LOG settings,Enable the APP LOG function.
The procedure for capturing logs is as follows:
1. Run the following command to connect to the device:
adb logcat -v time > D:\log.txt
2. Reproduce the problem scenario.
3. Press Ctrl+c to finish.

Comment: @shirely Tab page is written in MainActivity. Redirecting from notifications contols in MainActivity as well. It doesn't matter what lifecycle happen in fragments, because after second click onNew intent doesn't called and nothing happen. Normal situation like it works with gms pushs -> First push click -> App starts -> UpdateActivity start with intent and call start Main Activity with the same intent -> redirection happens -> second push click -> in UpdateActivity onNewIntent called and MainActivity start with the same intent -> redirections happen

Comment: The only problem is that onNewIntent NOT called and other actions not happen.

Comment: add logs from project menu

Comment: sorry after analysis, we find that looks like the problem that onNewIntent is not called is not caused by the push kit.

Comment: The problem is in the device or it is something else?